# How do I get good at animation even though I'm not good at drawing and digital art?

Tags: animation

I've been struggling for a long time to get good at animation. I'm a storyteller at heart, so I have been trying to write books for a long time. It's just that I'm a visual person and while I am getting into books, it's not something that I value above the other ways I can tell a story. Animation is something I know really well, since I grew up with cartoons, anime, and video games.

When it comes to digital art I always have trouble getting used to the interface and making good art on it. This involves any program really. I have been reading The Animators Survival Kit, but so far it hasn't helped me much. No matter what tutorial I watch, read, or listen to it doesn't really help. I don't know if it has to do with my mentality or procrastination or anxiety or whatever. I'm just a beginner artist, I haven't developed my style.

I seek to revolutionize animation. Since (in my opinion anyway) we're kind of limiting it with American animation almost always being comedic, web animation always being parody and usually not original, I'd talk about it more but I'd be here all day and it's not what I'm focusing on.

I only got into digital art and animation recently (2016 I think, it was when I was turning into an adult.)

Answer (score 2):

Hard work. One does not become a god in animation overnight.

Learn to master Illustrator, Photoshop, After Effects. That's virtually all you need for professional animation. Or go and look for programs that fit your workflow best and stick with them. Don't try to be "moderate" at every program, master your few.

There are great books and masterclasses and guides on sites such as pluralsight. Create something, realize it sucks, do it again, improve. That's the natural way all of us had to learn design, animation, compositing etc.

Answer (score 1):

Practice. Practice. Practice.
If you can't draw at all, try stop-motion animation.
Ask yourself: what do I find compelling about animation? What does it do that no other form of expression does? I'm asking this because you yourself mention that you can't draw nor really get in digital animation. And yet, you persist. So, why? Are you sure it's not the stories that you like?

Also, no need to *master* any program to start animating. That's putting the bar way too high. But you will eventually, just by using these programs over and over again.

Learn the basics of Premiere Pro, or Photoshop or Affinity Photo (cheaper!), or iMovie if you have a Mac. And start doing stop motion stuff. Animate beans on a counter. One bean is one color, and the others are something else. Tell your story. Whatever you do though, keep it simple! You're not going to "revolutionize animation" overnight.
Animate play-dough. Then start using sounds, as demonstrated in this video [Animation Tutorial with Tips and Tricks](https://youtu.be/-uIQpReF1Nc)

Find a group of like-minded people you could work with. no tutorial or book will ever teach you enough. Talk to people. Make connections. Work on projects.

If you can't draw and can't take animating things image per image in some program, write. Write your scripts. Feels to me that that is where your strength is.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. However I don't think stop motion is the type of animation I want to make. I mostly do 2d animation because drawing is what I put my mind to, recently at least. Plus drawings are what I'm into. So yeah.